# Battery not detected in my LG laptop - 16.04

Tags: power-management, battery

`acpi -b` returns nothing. `acpi -a` says `Adapter 0: off-line` even though it is online. There's no `BAT0` file in `/sys/class/power_supply/`, only a symbolic link to a directory called `ACAD`. I tried adding `acpi=force` into `/etc/default/grub` and `sudo grub-update` then rebooting, but nothing changes.  Unplugging my AC connector and plugging it in again has no effect.

It's a two-week old laptop, and I'm getting worried that I'm not going to be able to use Linux on it. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Is this a laptop with a brand new CPU/Chipset? Like Intel Kaby lake? If it is, try Ubuntu 16.10. If it has an older CPU though, it probably won't make any difference.

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes it is. It's Kaby Lake, and I installed 16.10 before installing 16.04  again because [Nvidia drivers caused boot hanging](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1633172). The battery still wasn't detected in 16.10 though, as I remember. Ah, I'll just have to wait untill the issue's fixed then.

Comment: You could try a bleeding-edge kernel.